# GWT: Organizing WAR with multiple modules

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, war

I'm trying to create a GWT app that has two modules:

- `WebModule` - that contains all the code that will appear to be the "public website"; and
- `AppModule` - gets loaded only after the user signs in (via a `LoginScreen` inside the `WebModule`) for security and performance reasons

I'm unsure of how to package the WAR. With one module (that contains an Entry Point), the normal structure seems to be this:

```
src/
    com.myapp
        MyApp.gwt.xml
    com.myapp.client
        MyApp.java
war/
    WEB-INF/
        lib/
        web.xml
    MyApp.css
    MyApp.html
```

But with 2+ modules, I'm confused as to where I can/should place the various files. I'd like to do something like this:

```
src/
    com.myapp
        WebModule.gwt.xml
        AppModule.gwt.xml
    com.myapp.client.modules
        WebModule.java (implements EntryPoint)
        AppModule.java (implements EntryPoint)
war/
    WEB-INF/
        lib/
        web.xml
    css/
        web-module.css
        app-module.css
    html/
        web-module.html
        app-module.html
```

But I'm unsure if this is "legal" (GWT and Java EE standards) structure or not, and I'm also unsure as to how to link "MyApp" with the "WebModule" so that `WebModule` is the first module downloaded when the user goes to `http://www.myapp.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right structure. You don't have to create separate folders for HTML and CSS, though, as you only have two files in each.

You specify which file loads first, when users visit your domain, in web.xml file:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>web-module.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrei Volgin (+1) - quick question: do I *have* to place `WebModule.gwt.xml` and `AppModule.gwt.xml` under the `src/com.myapp` package, or could I place them, say, under `war/gwt/xml`? Thanks again!

Comment: They have to be in the src folder. The compiler needs to read these files.